# Watson minecraft dialog does not start

Tags: ibm-cloud, minecraft, ibm-watson

I followed the tutorial at
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-bluemix-minecraft-watson-trs-4/
But the disease Dialog.xml is missing.  So I used the following instead:
http://planetlotus.org/profiles/niklas-heidloff_140956

The dialog works fine in Watson dialog-tool, but not in the tutorial context.  I deployed the container to Bluemix and connected to the server from Minecraft and it still does not start the dialog.

Tried to follow `https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dialog-nodejs`
But run into the following error after the 'cf push watsonspigotbluemix' command:

```
Starting app watsonspigotbluemix in org / space as ..
-----> Downloaded app package (2.4M)
Staging failed: An application could not be detected by any available buildpack

FAILED
NoAppDetectedError
```

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are receiving means your current working direction did not contain the necessary files to detect the language.

Check out this link for more help: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/29319/not-able-to-deploy-application-for-nodejs-application.html